# How to solve recursive equations $F_{n+1} = F_{n} \cdot g + h$

Tags: recursion

Sorry if this is a duplicate or easy (a lot of the other 'how do i solve recursive equation' questions were for more complex equations). How can I solve this for arbitrary $F_n$ with arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

$$F_{n+1} = F_{n} \cdot c_1 + c_2$$

Also does it matter if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants or would it work if they were functions themselves such as:

$$F_{n+1} = F_{n} \cdot g + h$$

Comment: You cant solve for "arbitrary" $F_n$, sometimes you can create a closed expression, sometimes not. I recommend you to read _Concrete math_ or [Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf).

Comment: You can start with a naive way: try to calculate explicitly some first $F$, for example, given $F_0=a$ what $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_3$, $F_4$ would be (solve by substitution)? After that you will most likely guess the solution for $F_k$.

Comment: Matrices are nice to do this. You can express $F_{n+1}$ as a matrix exponent. But it is a little bit difficult to explain it without any concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$
F_{n+1} = F_n c_1 + c_2.
$$

## Case $c_1 \ne 1$

We can write
$$
F_{n} = G_{n} - \zeta.
$$

Then we obtain
$$
\underbrace{G_{n+1} - \zeta}_{\displaystyle F_{n+1}} =
\Big( \underbrace{G_{n} - \zeta}_{\displaystyle F_{n}} \Big) c_1 + c_2,
$$
so
$$
G_{n+1} = G_{n} c_1 + \underbrace{\zeta - \zeta c_1 + c_2}_{\displaystyle 0},
$$
thus
$$
c_1 \ne 0 : \zeta - \zeta c_1 + c_2 = 0 \Rightarrow \zeta = \frac{c_2}{c_1-1}.
$$
Let $c_1 \ne 1$, then we write
$$
F_{n} = G_{n} - \frac{c_2}{c_1-1}.
$$

Put this in recursion relation and we get
$$
G_{n+1} - \frac{c_2}{c_1-1} = G_{n} c_1 - \frac{c_1 c_2}{c_1-1} + c_2.
$$

Whence we obtain
$$
G_{n+1} = G_{n} c_1.
$$

Therefore
$$
G_{n} = G_{0} c_1^n.
$$

Going back, we get

> > $$
> > F_{n} = \Big( F_{0} + \frac{c_2}{c_1-1} \Big) c_1^n
> >      - \frac{c_2}{c_1-1}.
> > $$

---

Simple check:
$$
\begin{array}{rclc}
F_{n+1} &=& \displaystyle \Big( F_{0} + \frac{c_2}{c_1-1} \Big) c_1^{n+1}
     - \frac{c_2}{c_1-1}.\\
F_{n} c_1 &=& \displaystyle \Big( F_{0} + \frac{c_2}{c_1-1} \Big) c_1^{n+1}
     - \frac{c_1 c_2}{c_1-1}.\\
&&&-\\
\hline\\
F_{n+1} - F_{n} c_1 &=& \displaystyle
     \frac{c_1 c_2}{c_1-1} - \frac{c_2}{c_1-1} = c_2.
\end{array}
$$

---

More general, we can write

> > $$F_{n} = \Big( F_1 - F_0 c_1 \Big) c_2 \frac{c_1^n-1}{c_1-1} + F_0 c_1^n.$$

Comment: how do you get to your second step F_n=G_n−c_2/c_1−1 ?

Comment: @Letseatlunch, you can general write $F_n = G_n + c$, where $c$ is a constant, put it in and you can remove the constant term by selecting $ = c_2 / (c_1 - 1 )$...

Comment: how did you pick c2/(c1-1) as your constant c? it's not obvious to me.

Comment: @Letseatlunch, I added extra steps in the post. Hope it is clear now...

Comment: thanks, I think I get it now :)

Comment: just a note to myself we set ζ−ζc1+c2 = 0 so we can obtain Gn+1=Gnc1

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the constants, assuming $F_0 = s$, a simple induction proof will yield that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$F_n = c_1^ns + c_2\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} c_1^i\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You can solve these with matrix powers.
$$A_0 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}g&0&0\\h&0&0 \\F_0&1&0 \end{array}\right)$$
we see that
$$({A_0}^2)_{3,1} = gF_0+h+0 = F_1$$
Just keep multiplying to the left with $A_0$ and you will get next element at position (3,1) in the matrix.
Maybe you need to calculate $g$ or $h$ as a function of $n$, but there are ways do to this with matrix multiplication for many types of functions.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read more about this technique? I understand matrices at a basic level but don't understand how this helps solve the problem.

Comment: I would also like to find more places to read about it. The most similar thing I've seen so far is probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group.

Comment: So you should probably read more about groups. You can do that in some introductory course in abstract algebra.